# Scala Regex ReplaceAll: How to Replace All Groups?

Tags: scala

The following regex replace works beautifully:

```
var line = "PRIMARY INDEX XPKDLRSRC_PMT_CLMPMT ( DLRSRC_PMT_ID ,DLRSRC_PMT_CLMPMT_ID );"
println(line.replaceAll("""[UNIQUE\s]{0,1}PRIMARY INDEX [^\s]* \(""", "PRIMARY KEY ("))
```

It returns: `PRIMARY KEY ( DLRSRC_PMT_ID ,DLRSRC_PMT_CLMPMT_ID );`

The point of the first group `[UNIQUE\s]` was to take care of the following as well

```
line = "UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX XPKDLRSRC_PMT_CLMPMT ( DLRSRC_PMT_ID ,DLRSRC_PMT_CLMPMT_ID );"
println(line.replaceAll("""[UNIQUE\s]{0,1}PRIMARY INDEX [^\s]* \(""", "PRIMARY KEY ("))
```

But the word `UNIQUE` does not get replaced and I end up with

`UNIQUEPRIMARY KEY ( DLRSRC_PMT_ID ,DLRSRC_PMT_CLMPMT_ID );`

When I expected

`PRIMARY KEY ( DLRSRC_PMT_ID ,DLRSRC_PMT_CLMPMT_ID );`

How to I get all groups in the regex replaced by a string?

Comment: Don't use `var`

Comment: [this tool](https://jex.im/regulex/) is great for visualising regular expressions. `https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5BUNIQUE%5Cs%5D%7B0%2C1%7DPRIMARY%20INDEX%20%5B%5E%5Cs%5D*%20%5C(` shows what your regular expression actually does. (Can't make this a link in a comment for some reason)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[UNIQUE\s]` represents a single character consisting of any of the enclosed characters.  For what you need, replacing it with `(?:UNIQUE\s+)?` should do.

```
val line = "UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX XPKDLRSRC_PMT_CLMPMT ( DLRSRC_PMT_ID ,DLRSRC_PMT_CLMPMT_ID );"

line.replaceAll("""(?:UNIQUE\s+)?PRIMARY INDEX [^\s]* \(""", "PRIMARY KEY (")
// res1: String = PRIMARY KEY ( DLRSRC_PMT_ID ,DLRSRC_PMT_CLMPMT_ID );
```

`(?:`regex`)` represents a non-capturing group and appending the group with a `?` makes it an optional match.